# Finesse=amazing (word choice)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, parts-of-speech

Let's say you are describing a newly built building in your hometown. You say it is amazing:

> The new building has a **finesse** architectural design.

An American say it is wrongly used. But an online dictionary define "finese" as:
[description click here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/finesse). I doubt what the American said, help.

Comment: That definition says “finesse” is a noun. Is that how you’re using it in your sentence?

Comment: As an adjective...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the dictionary says that *finesse*, with the meaning you are looking for, is a **noun**. It is not an adjective. If it were, it could modify *design*. Nor is it an adverb, which could modify the adjective *architectural*.

So, you could say that its architecture ***shows finesse***, or it was designed ***with finesse***, but you can't use *finesse* to modify an adjective or noun.

You can use *finesse* as a verb, but as a verb it usually relates to trickery and guile, or cunning evasion of obstacles and mistakes. If it *shows* finesse, that is saying it shows style, elegance, or the characteristics of being done well. The same is true if it was done *with* finesse.

Comment: However, you could say: *The new building has a **finessed** architectural design.* That uses the verb form—but my instinct tells me it's being used adjectivally in that sentence. (And it doesn't sound wrong to me.)